# Delete a "base" branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

Originally, there was the **master** branch.

Then I've create a **feature_1** branch from **master**, to implement *feature 1*.

After some work on this new branch, I decided to implement *feature 2*, that depends from *feature 1* so I did:

```
$ git checkout -b feature_2 feature_1
```

I did some work on **feature_2** branch.

Now, it has no sense to continue developments on **feature_1** branch since all its developments are included in **feature_2** branch.

Is it "safe" to delete **feature_1** branch even if it's the base from which I started **feature_2** branch?
After the deletion, will I see in the Git graph a single **feature_2** branch starting from the **master** branch?

What I would like to achieve is what written above, a single **feature_2** branch starting from **master** branch at the same point when I started **feature_1** branch. Finally, rename it as **feature_1_2** branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens in the child branch if I delete a parent branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380840/what-happens-in-the-child-branch-if-i-delete-a-parent-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
# Delete branch feature_1
git branch -d feature_1

# Rename feature_2 -> feature_1_2
git branch -m feature_2 feature_1_2
```

If you want to make sure that there is no additional work on `feature_1` (i.e. commits that are not in `feature_2`), you can do a fast-forward merge:

```
git checkout feature_1
git merge --ff-only feature_2
```

If the merge succeeds, `feature_1` and `feature_2` point to the same commit. So it is safe to delete one of them.

Comment: So is it completely safe to delete the branch **feature_1** even if **feature_2** started from it?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have done work on feature_1 after you started feature_2.

Comment: No, it's a "dead-end"

Comment: I have added some more git-foo to make sure that you'll not lose any work.

Answer (score 0):

I think If you delete feature_1, your feature_2 will be lost. So commit feat2 then del feat1